# How to create a single quotation expression from a collection of expressions?

Tags: .net, f#, quotations

I have a collection of (sub) quotation expressions that are all created in a prior step in a program. I now want to be able to control the creation of one single large quotation expression that represents some composition & aggregation of the sub expressions in the collections but can't get the compiler or runtime to co-operate!

My code sample is below:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let expr0 = <@ fun (r : float[]) -> r.[1] @>
    let expr1 = <@ fun (r : float[]) -> 1.0 + r.[0] @>
    let expr2 = <@ fun (r : float[]) -> 10.0 * r.[0] @>
    let expr3 = <@ fun (r : float[]) -> r.[0] * r.[1] @>
    let expr4 = <@ fun (r : float[]) -> (r.[0]-2.0) / (r.[1]-9.0) @>

    let exprs = [|expr0; expr1; expr2; expr3; expr4|]

    let arbInput = [|1.0; 2.0; 3.0; 4.0; 5.0|]
    let arbOrder = [|0;4;1;3;4;2|]

    let tree = <@ arbOrder |> Array.map (fun x -> (%(exprs.[x]) <| arbInput)) @> //cannot use the variable `x` as part of a spliced expression 
    printfn "%A" tree

    System.Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0
```

Other errors received in other attempts at coercing this behaviour include: "can't treat ''%' and '%%' as first class..."

I have tried the steps mentioned in the answer to: [Code Quotations: how to access variables of a lambda function internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31093528/code-quotations-how-to-access-variables-of-a-lambda-function-internally) but I could not get to a solution.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that `x` is a quoted variable and you're trying to use its value while building the quotation, which is not possible. The use of `x` cannot be in an unquoted part. For this, you will need to use `Expr` functions to create an `Expr<T[]>` from your `Expr<T>[]`:

```
let makeQuotedArray (exprs: Expr<'T>[]) : Expr<'T[]> =
    Expr.NewArray(typeof<'T>,
        exprs |> Array.map (fun e -> e :> Expr) |> List.ofArray)
    |> Expr.Cast

let exprs = makeQuotedArray [|expr0; expr1; expr2; expr3; expr4|]

let tree = <@ arbOrder |> Array.map (fun x -> (%exprs).[x] arbInput) @>
```